# Can I shorten dataset for time-dependent analysis of factor due to death of subjects?

Tags: regression

I have a dataset on contaminant exposure of small critters, for which it visually appears to be a large increase in egg production over time for treatments exposed to the contaminant. The selected model shows no significant effect. However, most of the high producing animals died 15 days before the end of the experiment (total 55 days), and if I shorten the dataset in the model and exclude these last 15 days then I get a significant effect of the contaminant.

I am wondering if there is any valid reason to analyze the shortened time period in this manner when subjects are dying/lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing here is that you are not HARKing: hypothesizing after results are known. It is natural that we would prefer to publish 'statistically significant' results, but this should be done based on pre-defined analyses.

You have seen both your original model and the model when excluding the last 15 days and now know that the model with 15 days excluded actually gives you a significant effect. It is then easy to try and find reasons why the model with 15 days excluded would actually be a more valid model, but ask yourself the following:

- If both models were statistically  significant for the contaminant, would you have cared about the 40 days (15 days excluded) model?
- If the 55 day model was statistically significant but the 40 day model was not, would you have cared whether the 40 day model was valid?
- If both models were not statistically significant, would you have cared whether the 40 day model was valid?

Other than that, knowing if the model is valid is difficult to know without model specifications (what model, how was the model fit, etc.)

Comment: Thank you. I don't think that I would have cared about the shortened time period in either two cases you propose, as I can't think of why this would be relevant in itself. I might perhaps briefly mention that there was a an effect at 40 days, but that this leveled out with more time, as this can be an interesting point in itself considering study design. The model is a glmm with four factors (tem, ph, contaminant & days) and random intercept for ID using neg binomial distribution, if that is relevant:)